# Remove extra column title in esttab (Stata)

Tags: stata

I'm using `estout` to prepare regression tables for LaTeX. It seems when storing a nonlinear model, there is an extra row in the output that I can't seem to turn off or remove. As an MWE, consider:

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear 
eststo: poisson mpg rep78 
esttab, tex nomti nodepvars
```

This will produce output with a row after the model numbers and before the coefficients with "mpg" (the dependent variable) in the left-most column and the other columns blank. This is not a model title and the `nomti` and `nodepvars` options will not remove it.

Oddly, this row does not show up when the regression is OLS. However, this row does appear in the following example with OLS and Poisson, now containing "main":

```
sysuse auto, clear
eststo clear
eststo: reg mpg rep78
eststo: poisson mpg rep78
esttab, tex nomti nodepvars
```

I've been through the options in `esttab` and `estout` and I can't find any that seem to turn off this row (I'm not even sure what purpose it might serve). Any ideas how to get rid of this row?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the option `eqlabels(none)` to your esttab.

Answer (score 3):

@Dimitriy has posted the solution.

As a side note, consider *why* this is happening:

The matrix of coefficients for `regress` looks like:

```
. matrix list e(b)

e(b)[1,2]
        rep78      _cons
y1  2.3842975  13.169421
```

while that for `poisson`:

```
. matrix list e(b)

e(b)[1,2]
          mpg:       mpg:
        rep78      _cons
y1  .11242548  2.6692439
```

`estout`, `esttab`, etc. use these **stored results**, therefore the tables.